# Является ли данная реализация оповещений по email костылем?

Tags: python, django, инспекция-кода

Задача: к посту добавляется комментарий - автору поста приходит сообщение на email
реализовал я через `signals`

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Answer)
def send_email_after_answer(**kwargs):
    instance = kwargs['instance']
    send_mail(
        'subject',
        'Here is the message',
        settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        [f'{instance.post.author.email}'],  # post - связывает модель комментариев и поста, далее у автора поста берем email и подставляем
        fail_silently=False,
    )
```

Когда я начинал разбираться в этом вопросе, гуглил решения и все не то. В решениях было много ненужных строк кода, и из-за этого появилось такое ощущение что получился костыль, хотя работает все полностью исправно.

В итоге, по вашему мнению, является ли этот код нормальным для данной задачи? И как бы вы это реализовали? Всем спасибо!

Comment: `post_save` — то есть при любом редактировании комментария будет опять отправляться email? Не уверен, что это хорошо

Comment: @andreymal, да, вы правы, как бы вы реализовали это?

Comment: возможно данный ответ вам поможет https://stackoverflow.com/a/72338143/18027287